# Arranging Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array like which is sorted by category

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => JOHN
        [category] => abc
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => JOHN
        [category] => abc
    )

[2] => Array
    (
    [name] => JOHN
        [category] => abc
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => John6
        [category] => cvb
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => John6
        [category] => cvb
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => Outfit7
        [category] => cvb
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => John6
        [category] => cvb
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [name] => Joh8
        [category] => fgh
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [name] => JOHN
        [category] => fgh
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [name] => John9
        [category] => fgh
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [name] => JOHN
        [category] => fgh
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [name] => John0
        [category] => fgh
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [name] => Johny
        [category] => fgh
    )
)
```

Now i want to this array deep multidimensional array from category means some thing like:

```
Array
{
[abc] => Array
         {
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => JOHN MOFFETT
                    [category] => abc
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => JOHN MOFFETT
                    [category] => abc
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => JOHN MOFFETT
                    [category] => abc
                )
         }
[cvb] => Array
         {
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John Miller
                    [category] => cvb
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John Slater
                    [category] => cvb
                )
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Outfit7
                    [category] => cvb
                )
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John Slater
                    [category] => cvb
                )
         }
}
```

and so on. Till now tried many ways using foreach loop and for loop but no success. Can any one give me idea on how to do this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking.  Can you please clarify?  Are you asking how to convert from the first array to the second one?  Or are you asking how to loop through the second array and do meaningful things with its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

$tmp = ' ' ;

$new_Array = array();

```
foreach($category_array as $cat_id => $cat)
{
   $tmp = $cat['category'];  
   $new_array[$tmp][$cat_id] = $cat;
}
```

Cheers !!

Comment: @deceze: removed $tmp keyword and according updated second statement. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

thank you, i was searching same thing like this. Upvote Sent :) not have reputataion to comment so doing it this way. Hope you dont mind.

Comment: Dont worry dude you will soon have prov to comments :)  !! You are always welcome !!